# Problemas con BUSCARV e IMPORTRANGE

Tags: google-hoja-de-cálculo

Hice una hoja de cálculo en Google sheet que después descargué para editar unas cosas en Excel.   Las edité correctamente incluyendo las fórmulas.  Al importar dicha página de vuelta a Google sheets la formula me da el siguiente error "VLOOKUP evalúa como un intervalo fuera de los límites."  Lo extraño es que esta misma fórmula la tengo en otra hoja de cálculo google y funciona perfectamente.   Esta es la formula: 
`=SI(B1=84;BUSCARV(84;IMPORTRANGE("https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1QHFk-0ADpRxH7jOS8OixB7nfhCTqE36T8WF651PUzY/edit#gid=214006245";"DP!A:O");5;FALSO);"SIN LLENAR")`

Gracias por su ayuda.

Comment: No está claro a que se refiere la pregunta. ¿Convertiste la hoja de cálculo de Excel o una hoja de cálculo de Google o subiste la hoja de cálculo a Excel a Google Drive y estás editándola con la extensión de Chrome para editar archivos de Office en Google Drive?

Comment: Sr Ruben cambié todo el texto de la pregunta a ver si así me puedo hacer entender mejor.

Comment: Sr Ruben, no entiendo nada pero de repente la formula comenzó a funcionar.  Claro ahora me preocupa que deje de funcionar.    No se si tiene una sugerencia o probable solución

Comment: No se deben incluir saludos, despedidas, gracias en la pregunta, sólo la información necesaria para entender la situación.

Comment: Me alegra que haya resulto el problema. En cuanto a la pregunta, está mejor pero aún no tiene suficiente información. ¿La fórmula que da problemas la agregaste en la hoja de cálculo de Google antes de modificarla en Excel o la agregaste en Excel? IMPORTRANGE require autorización para acceder datos en otra hoja cada vez que se usa en archivos distintos y la primera vez que accede a un archivo externo. Para facilitar identificar esto te sugiero evitar poner IMPORTRANGE dentro de otras funciones.

Comment: Estimado, te dejo un enlace sobre el uso de la función IMPORTRANGE.  Entre otras cosas, no es buena idea ponerlo dentro de una fórmula.  Conviene hacer una hoja que traiga importe el rango completo, y luego las fórmulas tomen los datos de ahí.
https://hojasdecalculogoogle.blogspot.com/2013/06/importx-vincular-datos-de-otras-hojas.html